# Error: __WXMSW__||No such file or directory| while building the project in Code::Blocks WxWidgets C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm trying to use WxWidgets in Code::Blocks but have failed to build my binaries, hence I decided to use the precompiled ones. It gives an error:  `__WXMSW__||No such file or directory|` when I click "Build" in Code::Blocks.

I've added `__WXDEBUG__` in the #define tab of the (project name's) debug category. I guess this is the reason for the error. I'm new to C++ and WxWidgets. Am I doing anything wrong? I've followed the instructions in https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxWidgets_Pre-Built_Binary_in_CodeBlocks. Is the `__WXDEBUG__` incorrect? If not, what is the mistake I've made?

Comment: what problem did you have building wxWidgets? What platform and wx version you tried? What compiler and its version?

Comment: I tried using WxWidgets 3.0.5 and I think Windows (my PC is Windows). Only this was in the Build log: g++.exe: error: ___WXMSW___: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: wxUSE_UNICODE: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s). Does this help? @Igor

I used the GNU GCC Compiler but I don't know its version. Is there a way to check its version? I selected it from the Code::Blocks' combobox.

Comment: The problem I had building WxWidgets was again an error: `wx/wx.h: No such file or directory`. I had followed the instructions in https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CodeBlocks_Setup_Guide.

Comment: ***what is the mistake I've made?*** Most likely your mistake was in whatever folder you added for the include directories setting in your IDE did not have a wx folder contained in the folder you added.

Comment: @drescherjm No, the `E:\...\<Main folder>\include\wx` is the wx folder. Is someother wx folder missing?

Comment: Instead of trying to configure codeblocks yourself to use wxWidgets, you should use the new project wizard to create a wxWidgets project.  It's a little tricky because the settings you use for the wizard must match the settings used when building the wxWidgets library, but [the pdf linked from ths page](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231) is a really good guide that walks you through the entire process.

Comment: I think the folder you added should be: `E:\...\<Main folder>\include` unless the `E:\...\<Main folder>\include\wx\wx\wx.h` file exists.

Comment: @EEE, what exact command did you use to build the library? What compiler and its version?

Comment: @drescherjm no, the folder I added was `E:\...\<Main folder>\include`, and the wx folder's path is `E:\...\<Main folder>\include\wx`. Also, my there isn't a `E:\...\<Main folder>\include\wx\wx\wx.h` file. How do I generate that?

Comment: @Igor the command I used is `mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=0` as mentioned in https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CodeBlocks_Setup_Guide. I selected the `GNU GCC Compiler` from the combobox in Code::Blocks in Project>Build Options>Selected compiler. Could you please tell where the compiler is, so I can find it's version in its filename?

Comment: @EEE, couple of commentsd. Is there a reason you turn off the UNICODE support? The only purpose for MONOLITHIC build is if you plan to work on the C::B itself. If you plan to do some development outside the scop[e of C::B - you should turn this off. If you are on Windows its usually preferred to build with `SHARED=0`, unless you plan tyo develop DLL yourself. But I want to know what errors did you encounter during the build. I believe they all will relate to UNICODE being off.....

Comment: @EEE, Now to answer the actual question - as mentioned above already you should create a wxWidgets project in C::B by using an appropriate template.

Comment: @Igor no, I haven't created a WxWidgets project using Code::Blocks' wizard. That's what I'm trying to but I'm also ok W configuring WxWidgets myself (I've built WxWidgets, unable to use it). All the Build options I've set are for an Empty Project that I created as in the tutorial. That's when I get the `__WXMSW__||No such file or directory|` error. So, I tried using Code::Blocks' wizard but don't know what to check and what to enter in the `Configurations: ` box. I tried checking different combinations, still it says A matching debug configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory...

Comment: @EEE, as I said, start with simple wxWidgets configuration. `mingw32-make -f makefile USE_XRC=1 SHARED=0 BUILD=debug`. Then follow this: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231 detailed instructions on setting up C::B with wxWidgets.

Comment: @Igor oh, thanks a lot!

Comment: As said above `MONOLITHIC` is only used by C::B itself, so unless you plan on working on it or fixing bugs inside the C::B itself - you should drop this option. In the XXI century - UNICODE should absolutely be a default option, not even to support i18n, but because you need to support different languages. And you should always start with the `DEBUG` configuration - especially if its something un-familiar...

Comment: And I think USE_XRC is the default one - I just include it for compatibility with you current option.

Comment: @EEE, please read my following comment, understand it and follow thru with PB guide. `MONOLITHIC` build should really be dropped a long time ago, but core devs keeping it just for C::B developers. The prices for the HDD are not high to satisfy the monolithic build requirement. ;-)

Comment: @Igor thank you so much! It worked for me :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.